# Create columns for each categoric value in R

Tags: r

I have a df called "homes", it has two columns: "Education level" and "Insurance". Ed level is a categoric variable has four leves: Primary, High-Sch, Terciary and College. For instance:

```
Ed.Level. Insurance
Primary.    YES
Primary.    NO
Primary.    NO
College.    YES
College.    YES
High-Sch.   YES
High-Sch.   NO
Terc.       YES
```

I need to create a new column with name: Primary with values: YES, NO, etc. and the same logic for each education level.
The expected output would be:

```
Primary. Secondary  High Sch  College
YES.       NO.        YES.     NO
NO.        YES.       NO.      YES
YES.       YES        YES.     NO
NO.        YES        YES.     YES
```

The values in the expected output are refered to the Insurance field.

I tried with a transpose and didn't work, cbind, merges, but nothing worked.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You need `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(data.table); df1 %>% mutate(rn = rowid(Ed.Level.)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Ed.Level., values_from = Insurance)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`pivot_wider`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidytable/versions/0.6.2/topics/pivot_wider.) to reshape into 'wide' format after creating a sequence column with [`rowid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/rowid) to take care of duplicate rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(Ed.Level.)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Ed.Level., values_from = Insurance) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Ed.Level. = c("Primary.", "Primary.", "Primary.", 
"College.", "College.", "High-Sch.", "High-Sch.", "Terc."), Insurance = c("YES", 
"NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "YES")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```